# How to force csv writer to include \n's, instead of creating newlines?

Tags: python, csv, unicode, newline

While working on a Twitter scraping project recently, I noticed that the tweets I scrape sometimes have the newline character in them - `\n` - which means that there are line-breaks in some tweets.

This is a problem for the `.csv` files I am creating with the scraped tweets, because Python's `csv.writer` keeps interpreting them as new lines, and my `.csv`'s thus become littered with line-breaks everywhere.

This is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNKmo.jpg) of a `.csv` I made, with line-breaks where `\n`'s were detected, and this is the code I am using to write each tweet in, one at a time,

```
with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([
        status.created_at, status.author.screen_name,
        len(status.text), status.favorite_count, status.retweet_count,
        status.text
    ])
```

I don't want to simply do `string.replace("\n", " ")` each time, as that does not seem to be efficient to me, and I have tried opening the csv with options like `newline='\n'`, but they do not seem to work for me.

How could I tell the `csv.writer` to not create new lines whenever it sees `\n`'s?

Comment: The convention in CSV files is that cells containing newlines are quoted. Any proper CSV writer already does that.

Comment: Somehow, I cannot find the way to do it with Python's CSV writer; could you tell me which options I should be looking at?

Comment: Show your existing code that isn't working, and the actual vs. desired result.  `csv.writer` will quote fields with embedded newlines.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.writer` quotes strings with `\n`

```
>>> import csv
>>> import io
>>> filestream = io.StringIO()
>>> csvwriter = csv.writer(filestream)
>>> csvwriter.writerow(["a", "a\n", "b"])
10
>>> filestream.getvalue()

'a,"a\n",b\r\n'
```

Notice `"a\n"` being in double quotes.

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do, if I am writing tweets with `csvwriter.writerow([..., ...])`, to make the `\n`'s be interpreted only as strings?

Comment: This is quoting, not escaping.

Comment: @Coolio2654 What interprets `\n` as a string?

Comment: My scraper detects linebreaks as `\n`'s in each tweet, and converts them to said strings, but my csv writer then takes the `\n`'s and converts them back into linebreaks again; I would just like to avoid that last part.

Comment: @Coolio2654 I don't think I understand you. I have shown in this answer that `csv.writer` quotes `\n` in values. In this case `\n` is not treated a new line but is a part of value by [`csv` definition](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2).

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know where in my tweet the `\n` is going to show up - as such, I cannot put the double quotes around them ahead of time, I simply need to tell `csvwriter` to treat `\n`'s as strings as a rule, whenever they show up.

Comment: I think I understand our confusion now. Your example is how I would want it to work, but on my setup, with Python 3.7, my code interprets `\n`'s as newlines:
`with open(file_name, 'a') as f:;
                        writer = csv.writer(f);
                        writer.writerow([*some_text_with_\n's*])` What could be the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: @Coolio2654 Could you show the concrete example with exact text you write `some_text_with_\n` and what you finally see written in `file_name`?

Comment: @Coolio2654 I believe the main reason you haven't got the answer yet is because nobody could understand what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited my question to be much clearer now, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Coolio2654 What I see on the screenshot is the correct `csv`. You opened it in a text editor which renders it as normal text with '\n' being displayed as new lines. If you open it in editor which can handle `csv` properly, it will not show it as new rows, but just a part of the value (notice quotes which denote it is a part of the value). Try importing it to Google Sheets, it should handle quotes correctly, so you will see it as one row.